# MS Project 2013 - SubProject Finish Date not Calculating Correctly

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I have a Master Project with a subproject. Inside the subproject there are two tasks. If opened alone and calculated (F9) the subproject finish date will roll up correctly.  If the Master Project is opened and calculated (F9) then it will roll up differently (and incorrectly.)  Why is this the case?

This is the Master Project (with the subproject linked) before calculation. As you can see, after the calculation it should show ID 1 to finish on 8/24/15 being the latest task date.

Before Calculation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHFsA.jpg

After Calculation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPBp2.jpg

As you can see, after the calculation it shows the finish date of the project at 8/8/14 instead of the later date 8/24/15 but shows the correct finish date on the Project Summary task of the Master Project.

What is going on?

Update * Just as an update. We believe it is a problem with the MS Project Pro 2013 updates. If we uninstall all MS Project updates it will calculate as expected. If we open in in MS Project 2016 it will calculate as expected.

This is still a serious calculation problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should have been resolved by the update released on Dec 6.  Try installing the public update and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: This did fix the issue.